# Are compression fitting deamed water proof

Tags: breaker-box

Are compression fittings on 2 inch conduit for the meter socket and weather head installation deamed waterproof?

Comment: I don't know that it even matters if they are - all exterior conduit is defined as a wet location.

Comment: In 2015, prob. Now they come with plastic bushings. Not sure about 2" tho.

Answer (score 1):

they have to be listed nec 358.42couplings and connectors referrs back to 314.15 that says they have to be listed, I usually use ridgid out side but there have been a few cases I have used compresson when it is away from people and equipment, I just looked up the ones I have done this with and they are listed as concreet tight (no other specific listing)but the inspector did pass the install (i usually use screw type) so the inspector probably figured they were listed... I did find some that are listed not sure what the difference is O ring or some additional seal? (I did not ask is this EMT or PVC conduit) I rarely use PVC in an industrial facility so I will check those out also. ok I am a dummy you glue PVC so for a box end or coupling there should be no compresson fitting
ao I go back to the part must be listed some are some are not

Answer (score 1):

Whatever type of conduit it is, a compression fitting would have to be listed as raintight for use out in the weather.  RMC threaded connections and PVC glued connections are waterproof / raintight and I'd say these are the better way to go.  In some locales EMT is not allowed outdoors.